# How to create a 0-arity method without parenthesis using Scala 3 low-level typed AST metaprogramming API?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

How can I create a 0-arity method without parenthesis using Scala 3 low-level typed AST metaprogramming API?

I tried this:

```
Refinement(parent, "name", MethodType(Nil)(_ => Nil, _ => TypeRepr.of[String]))
```

But it comes out as:

```
[error]    |    def name
[error]    |      (): String;
```

And if I try and call this refinement it complains with:

```
method name must be called with () argument
```

How can I get rid of the parenthesis?

Comment: From what I saw not all compiler's utilities are exposed in `Quotes` - some might become available in the future, but now we have to work around that limitation. I feel that the easiest way of doing what you need to do is to create some stub using quotes - e.g. `'{ new RandomType { def totallyRandomName: String = ??? } }` and then obtaining the `MethodType` of `totallyRandomName` or alternatively `TypeRepr.of[RandomType { def totallyRandomName: String }]` and then extracting that `MethodType` from this `TypeRepr`. If your refinement have harcoded types it should work (even if it feels wrong).